# Bluetooth low energy android doesn’t give me a real address only null name

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Can anyone help me? I want to scan nearby devices using bluetooth low energy but when I scan it give me random addresses with name null And this is my code:
I downloaded an app his name BLE scanner when I turn on BLE advertise on both phones after that I turn on my scan on my app it give me the real addresses otherwise nothing happened and my phone didn’t scan any phone :(

```
public void scanBLEDevices(Boolean       enable) {
 final ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
        Toast.makeText(BluetoothActivity.this, "result scan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
        String bluetoothAddressScanned = device.getAddress();
        Toast.makeText(BluetoothActivity.this, bluetoothAddressScanned + " "+device.getName()+result.getRssi(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      

    }

    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
        super.onBatchScanResults(results);
        Toast.makeText(BluetoothActivity.this, "result batch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
        Toast.makeText(BluetoothActivity.this, "ERRORRR scan!!!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder().
        setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER).
        setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
        .setMatchMode(ScanSettings.MATCH_MODE_AGGRESSIVE)
        //.setNumOfMatches(ScanSettings.MATCH_NUM_ONE_ADVERTISEMENT)
        .setReportDelay(0)
        .build();
/*final BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mscanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        Toast.makeText(BluetoothActivity.this, device.getName()+ " "+device.getAddress() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}; */

if(enable){
    if (bleScanner != null) {

       handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    bleScanner.stopScan(scanCallback);
                                 //   BA.stopLeScan(mscanCallback);
                                }
                            },30000);
       //BA.startLeScan(mscanCallback);
        bleScanner.startScan(null, scanSettings, scanCallback);
        //bleScanner.startScan(scanCallback);
    Toast.makeText(BluetoothActivity.this, "Scan Started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //lv.setAdapter(adapter);

} else {
    Toast.makeText(BluetoothActivity.this, "Couldn't get Scanner object", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
if(!enable) { try{
    bleScanner.stopScan(scanCallback);
   // BA.stopLeScan(mscanCallback);
    Toast.makeText(BluetoothActivity.this, "scan stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
    catch (IllegalStateException e){
        Toast.makeText(BluetoothActivity.this, "Illegal state exception "+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
   }
```

Comment: I don't understand the issue? Do you ask why it can't find any device when advertising on devices is disabled?

Comment: @AnatoliiChub for scan nearby devices should I add a method for advertising? Or only scanning?

Comment: BLE devices are detected through a procedure based on broadcasting advertising packets. This is done using 3 separate channels (frequencies), in order to reduce interference. The advertising device sends a packet on at least one of these three channels, with a repetition period called the advertising interval. For reducing the chance of multiple consecutive collisions, a random delay of up to 10 milliseconds is added to each advertising interval. The scanner listens to the channel for a duration called the scan window, which is periodically repeated every scan interval.

Comment: @AnatoliiChub thank you! One more question I can’t advertise with the public address? Or how can U send my own public address to the second phone? To save it

Comment: when device is advertising it's just send a message. And all devices that in scanning mode able to scan the message. I've attached a reference to my answer to the post. There you can find detailed description of advertising and scanning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Bluetooth devices send advertising packets (PDUs) to broadcast data,
> and to allow other devices (scanners) to find and connect to them.

So,if you don't have advertising devices nearby, you scanner will not find anything.
here you can find detailed information about advertising and scanning:

https://dev.ti.com/tirex/explore/node?node=AD4sGbaamTCyn0DvZgBAsg__krol.2c__LATEST